# Can a Symfony package be used in any PHP app without creating a Symfony App?

Tags: php, symfony

I like to use the [Constraints Helpers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) of Symfony in an existing, pure-php application. But is it possible to just use a small subset of functionality? When reading the docs, I am not sure about. Tutorials all start with creating a Symfony App from scratch with routing and everything done with Symfony.

Comment: `composer require symfony/validator`

Comment: yes you can ! make small and independant packages, is in the Symfony philosophy. Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html, the documentation is for pure php application :)

Comment: Symfony `components` (aka libraries) can be used independently though sometimes the documentation can be a bit lacking.  Symfony `bundles` (aka modules) require the framework.

Comment: The first blurb on symfony.com: _"Choose any of the 50 stand-alone components available for your own applications."_ and when you go to the "browse components"-page, the first sentence is: _"Symfony Components are decoupled libraries for PHP applications."_ :-) I use some of their components in almost all my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes just follow documentation here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html